# How does OpenGL function loading work?

Tags: c, opengl, sdl, glew

I understand it's necessary to "load" functions for opengl by having special functions locate pointers to the function based on the name of the opengl function. I've never seen something similar to this done before and I'm wondering how this works. Where are the functions actually located? How are they retrieved? Why is it done this way?

Comment: I don't really know the answer actually, but you can read this project : https://github.com/cginternals/glbinding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Where are the functions actually located?

This is implementation dependent. I'd wager that they're stored in a hash table of function names to function pointers. They're still in the shared library, but usually don't have their symbols exposed.

> How are they retrieved?

[glXGetProcAddress](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glXGetProcAddress.xml) or [wglGetProcAddress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374386(v=vs.85).aspx), depending on the platform. Most libraries that create OpenGL windows (GLFW, SDL) have their own, cross-platform function that uses the above.

> Why is it done this way?

I can think of a few reasons: implementations can change what extensions are available without breaking ABI compatibility, and what functions you have access to may depend on the type or version of context you request (ex. for Mesa, post OpenGL 3.1 extensions are only available in a 3.1+ context, not in anything lower).

Comment: can you elaborate a more on "shared library". Does this have anything to do with drivers for the gpu?

Comment: @Ragdoll A `.dll` or `.so` depending on the platform, that you link with `-l`. Google it